# getting a div id using javascript in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using laravel and  want to make an ajax call to retrieve the id of the product  but as u can see here it will get only the first  product id because they will have the same id (or the first when the page load)
but i want it to : when i press add to cart, the clicked product id is sent
and my skills are not that good , this is my first app, can any one help ?

here is the code

```
      @foreach($row as $product)
        <form method="post" id="reg-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="{{ $product->slug }}">
              {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-3 col-md-10 ">
              <div class='productbox '>
                  @if($image = $product->images()->first())
                      <img src="{{ $image->thumbnail }}  " class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                  @endif
                <div class="producttitle"><a href="{{ url('/product/'.$product->slug) }}">{{ $product->name }}</a></div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  @for ($i = 5 - $product->rating ; $i < 5 ; $i++)
                  <a>   <i class="price-text-color fa fa-star"></i></a>
                  @endfor
                  @for ($i = $product->rating ; $i < 5 ; $i++)
                <a>  <i class=" fa fa-star"></i></a>
                  @endfor
                  </div><br />
                <p class="text-justify"></p>
                <address class="ellipsis">
                    <strong>{{ $product->description }}</strong><br>
                  </address>
                <address>
                {{ $product->name }}<br>
                  </address>
                <div class="productprice">
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="button" id="getre" class="btn btn-danger btm-sm " role="button" value="Add to Wishlist">
                  </div>
                  <div class="pricetext">
                    <input type="submit" id="getRequest" class="btn btn-info btm-sm " role="button" value="Add to cart">
                    <a href="{{ url('/product/'.$product->slug) }}" class="btn btm-sm" role="button">More Details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></a>
                    <!--   <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btm-sm" role="button">Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a> -->
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          @endforeach
```

this is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(document).on('submit', '#reg-form', function()
 {
  var data = $("#post_id").val();

  $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url  : '{{url("/ajax")}}',
 data: {'name':data, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
  success :  function(data)
       {
         $(getRequest).replaceWith('<img id=getRequest width=50 height=40  src= http://www.cuisson.co.uk/templates/cuisson/supersize/slideshow/img/progress.BAK-FOURTH.gif> ');

         setTimeout(function() {
         $(getRequest).replaceWith('  <input type="submit" id="getRequest" class="btn btn-info btm-sm " role="button" value="Add to cart"> ').hide('blind', {}, 500)
       }, 1300);
      console.log(data);
       }
  });
  return false;
 });

});
```

Comment: Stopped reading at *"..they will have the same id"*, that's invalid, and the only solution is to change that. ID's are unique.

Comment: i mean i have a div id="stuff" ,  inside a foreach , the id will be the same for every div then ( i mentioned , my skill are low in js ) i hope uget the point ..and thats what  im asking, how to make them unique in a foreach and get them in js

Comment: Here's a tip: Replace all your `id="stuff"`s with `class="stuff"`, and then replace any matching JQuery selector `$('#stuff')` with `$('.stuff')`. If you want multiple classes, you can do so: `class="stuff border5"`

Comment: ok il keep that in mind :) thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get an element with id="post_id". There could be a lot of these elements in your page. You need to get the element with id="post_id" that is inside your current form element. You can do it in this way:

```
var data = $(this).find("#post_id").val();
```

Comment: ali , thanks a lot  , and thanks for anyone else :3 FIxed

Answer (score 0):

The model of your product should have a unique ID. So when you iterate over all your products, you should set the id of the div with the same ID of the model. Then you can get it with jquery by $(".your-product-div").attr("id")